# Consume an email API to send message

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am supposed to write a Spring Boot endpoint to read an API and send an email to stakeholders. Here is my code:

```
@PostMapping("/10.233.201.246:7070/VGIL/postal/email")
public Object sendEmail(){
    String to = "karim@gamil.com";
    String from = "helen@gmail.com";
    String subject = "Log files processing";
    String message = "The logs files has been created successfully";
    String cc = "baldemtaga@gmail.com";
    
    return null;
}

@GetMapping("/sendEmail")
public String postEmailToStakeholders(){
    String uri = "localhost:8080/api/10.233.201.246:7070/VGIL/postal/email";
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    return restTemplate.getForObject(uri, String.class, sendEmail());
}
```

Here is the API in Postman:

[image: Email API]

Comment: You may want to omit sensitive information such as email addresses.

Comment: Can you give more details? Do you read your data from another `API`? Do you have to implements two differents applications or `API`?

Comment: Yes, I have the email sender API already written in a file that is saved on my laptop my job is to call that API to send an email.

Answer (score 1):

Probably your endpoint should be

```
@PostMapping("/VGIL/postal/email")
```

if there aren't any other settings you can make a request from postman to this address

```
http://localhost:8080/VGIL/postal/email
```